# Parse HTML through Google Spreadsheet using scripting

Tags: google-sheets, html, google-apps-script

I'm trying to speed up the process of getting values from an HTML page to a Google Docs Spreadsheet through scripting.

I remember Microsoft Excel had the import data function, but I don't own a copy of that.

Is it possible to do this through Google Docs?

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to grab data that's stored in a list or table, you should use `=ImportHTML(URL,Type,Index)`.

Where Type is "List" or "Table" and index is which # table/list you want to import.

Documentation: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339

Answer (score 1):

You might want something like the [importXML or importHtml](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75507) functions? These will let you import an HTML page and use XPath to process the content.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at google commandline tools. You should be able to interact with google docs from a script easily with that.

http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/

Comment: The referred code project is broken according to a announcement on the code project homepage.